# Customizing Android ScrollView's Vertical Scrollbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-scrollview, android-styles

I need to customize `ScrollView` so it will look like in the picture:
[image]

I already successfully customized the `Thumb` and the `Track`, but I don't know how to add `Arrows` like in the picture I provided.
Here is the style I'm using:

```
<!-- Scrollbar -->
    <style name="scroll_view">  
        <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
        <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
        <item name="android:fadeScrollbars">false</item>
        <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/sb_thumb</item>
        <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/sb_track_vertical_bg</item>
    </style>
```

The `Arrows` should be a part of the `ScrollView` style to avoid extra spacing and also they need to be simple, non clickable and e.t.c.

Comment: Can't you simply insert the arrows in the drawable used for the track?

Comment: I can but then the scroll bar pointer will scroll over the arrows.

Comment: As a small hack, can't you also add some transparent space as big as the arrows parts on the thumb drawable?

Comment: I can for sure, but I want to know if I have more intelligent way to achieve the solution. Thank you.

Comment: I don't recall anything in the SDK for direct modification of the scroll bar of a view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add buttons for up and down, you can place two buttons above and below of Scrollview.And programatically scroll the scroll bar on button click.
For that purpose, you can use following code,

```
scrollview.scrollTo(5, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but must be a simpler way just to place even non-clickable header and footer to vertical track via the style.